# Can char-delimited string of email addresses work in msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail and MailMessage?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I've tested it and had inconsistent results, and that 's why I'm here.

I have one string `recipients`, that contains this string that's semicolon delimited: `"joe@msn.com; ron@outlook.com; mary@gmail.com; ted@yahoo.com; joe@hotmail.com"`. It can also be comma-delimited.

Can I use this string in both `MailMessage`/`SmtpClient` and `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`?

If possible, I would like to use one format for both (comma-delimited or semicolon delimited). It's no big deal if it's not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `String.Split()` and then just `foreach` over the `string[]` that is returned, sending an email to each address in the array?

Comment: I really asked out of curiosity. There are tons of ways to solve this, but I just wanted to know if one delimiter can be used for both.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, `MailMessage` is comma-delimited and `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` is semicomma delimited.